# How can i run an angular 6 application in wamp?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have an angular 6 application which i want to install on Apache server, is it possible??
I don't want to install ngix. Is it possible to run the application on Apache server?

Comment: have you tried ? Did you experimented any particular issue ? Why do you think it couldn't work ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11884
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348210/how-to-configure-apache-for-angular-2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070785/how-make-run-angular-4-with-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to deploy your Angular app you can follow the instruction of this link :

'https://angular.io/guide/deployment'

Just build the project with 'ng build' and then copy the folder inside './dist/' with the name of your project inside the apache server www directory.

Comment: i tried doing this.
But my page is going blank when i view the site.

Comment: Did you configure the href path in index.html properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can surely serve your application with Apache.

You need to configure your DocumentRoot as per your Angular Application Directory.

Additionally, you need to configure ReWriteEngine like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Follow the link for more details:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Thank you,
Punit